# record guitar chords with a pedal

Tags: homerecording

I sometimes see on youtube that guitarists play some chords and record them by using a pedal.

So, what is the device used to record chords as home backing tracks for my own solo playing?

Comment: It's a loop station and it's not cheap.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a ["looper"](https://www.sweetwater.com/c978--Loopers). Those are hardware looper pedals and they start at around $100. If you already have some other means of triggering a MIDI note with your foot, you can also use a [software looper](http://essej.net/sooperlooper/) of some kind.

Note that you may hear "looper" used in another context referring to a different kind of pedal. [Pedal board "loop switchers"](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/pedalboard-essentials-loop-switchers/) serve as routing controllers for large pedal boards so you can hook up a bunch of pedals and quickly switch between different routes without changing any cables. Those are also sometimes called "loopers". So just be aware that you're looking for the other kind.